# Why is BigDecimal's scale not a BigInteger?

Tags: java, biginteger, bigdecimal

Why is the `scale` field of a `BigDecimal` not a `BigInteger`? I assume currently it makes maybe no sense because calculations with that many decimal places are likely never performed, but wouldn't it make sense for the future to rather use a `BigInteger`?

Comment: No. These classes are slow enough as they are now. Anything to slow them down even more would be considered harmful.

Comment: Do you really need more than 2147483647 (more than 2 billions) digits after the decimal?

Comment: @Tunaki it is rather a theoretical question. Like I said now probably no one needs that many digits after the decimal point, but maybe in the future and as `BigDecimal`'s are from what I understood supposed to be limitted only by the available memory then this scale limit seems to counteract against this

Comment: With Java 10 we might get value types. And even arrays with more than an `int` for indexing. So maybe they will consider to overhaul BigDecimal too. Generally they can just use any value type instead of int. Maybe an unsigned 128 bit integer. That would still be better (faster) than BigDecimal.

Comment: BigDecimal is based on BigInteger, which can not hold many more than 2 billion digits anyway. Using a BigInteger for the scale would make the code a lot slower, and all the people who do not need 2 billion decimal digits (more than 99.99%) would have to suffer for those very very few who might need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scale of a BigDecimal is the number of digits it stores to the right of the decimal point.  It is an *amount of memory* in that those digits are actually stored, and it is an *amount of work* in that most operations on a BigDecimal will have to do work on all of those digits.

It is never going to be a good idea to use a BigDecimal that takes an amount of memory or work that doesn't fit into an int, so an int is used for scale.  That's the same reason int is used for string lengths and collection sizes, etc.

In the rare cases that a reasonable amount of memory or work doesn't fit into an int, it certainly fits into a long.  Longs are used for file sizes and position, for example.  A BigInteger is never required.